# Use both a pair and int value to a class using a typename

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have this class called Queue, which is using a typename.

```
template <typename Type>
class Queue {
private:
    int sz;

    struct element {
        Type val;
        element *next;

        element() {
            val = 0;
            next = nullptr;
        }
    };
    element *first, *last;
}
```

Now, if I want to make a Queue of type int, there is no problem. However, if I want to make another Queue of type pair, the line `val = 0;` throws an error, since `0` is not of type pair. Is there any way to avoid this, or generalize it?

Comment: Why not take a `Type` in `element`'s constructor?

Comment: Can you do `val = {};` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, both work, though I prefer @Den-Jason 's one, since I don't have to type the arguments every time.

Comment: `element` likely doesn't need a default constructor, anyway. Might need parameterized, copy, move, and assignment, but not default.

Comment: Why do you think `element()` must do something meaningful? Say your `Type` is a postal address. How do you construct a postal address of nowhere? What country is it in? If it's a person record, can you have a nobody in your database?